# How to know if Linkedin user is admin of his company on LinkedIn?

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I'm building a website using the LinkedIn Oauth api so that my visitors can log in using Linkedin. This works perfectly fine, but I now want to give people that are administrator for a company registered with Linkedin. When people log in I can get [different fields of info](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields) about them using the following:

```
people/~:(firstName,lastName,positions)
```

which gives me this:

```
{
    u'firstName': u'John',
    u'lastName': u'Doe',
    u'positions': {
        u'_total': 1,
        u'values': [
            {
                u'startDate': {
                    u'year': 2012
                },
                u'title': u'FreelanceProgrammer',
                u'summary': u'This is the summary of the company',
                u'isCurrent': True,
                u'id': 123456789
                u'company': {
                    u'industry': u'InformationTechnologyandServices',
                    u'size': u'MyselfOnly',
                    u'type': u'PublicCompany',
                    u'id': 1234567,
                    u'name': u'MyCompany'
                },
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't tell me anything about whether they are admins for their company on Linkedin.

Does anybody know if I can find out if the user is an admin for the company they work with? Or is there maybe way to get a list of the admins for the company? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an API call that you can make that tells you this, documented on LinkedIn's developer website at: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#is_admin

Additionally, you can get a list of all companies that the member is an administrator of with this call: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#list_companies

Comment: Thanks for that info! I just did a request using that url (for my own linkedin profile to my own company), but I get an error-response back saying `Member xxx does not have permission to get company xxx`. Does this mean that I (as a linkedin user) don't have permissions as an admin (even though I'm actually the only admin of my company) or does this mean that my code didn't get the correct `rw_company_admin` permission to request this info (even though it is listed under the `Default Application Permissions` in the linkedin app backend)? Any more info on this would be welcome!

Comment: Yes, you need to make that request with an oauth token that has the rw_company_admin permission for it to succeed.